# convert user-defined type to std::string in C++

Tags: c++, stringstream, stdstring, user-defined-types

If I have a user-defined type such as:

```
 typedef std::string GenderType;
 GenderType gender;
```

is it possible to set `gender` equal to a `std::string` variable?

```
 std::string temp;
 temp = gender;
```

Do I need to extract the `std::string` somehow from `GenderType`? Is it safer to do this using `stringstream`?

Comment: `typedef` introduces a synonym, another name for the same type. In other words, `std::string` and `GenderType` mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it's causing a crash, and my debugger isn't working b/c my pdb files are over 1GB hah

Comment: `GenderType` is just an alias for `std::string` what's the problem ?

Comment: I would not consider a `typedef` to be a user-defined type. `class`, `stuct`, and `union` declare user-defined types. `typedef` is just an alias to an existing type.

Comment: @squareskittles If your application crashes, it is not because of introducing a type alias for `std::string` but almost certainly because of something else we cannot see in your above post.  From a software engineering point of view: `std::string` is a poor choice for a `GenderType`.  An `enum` would probably be much better suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `typedef` you define a type alias, i.e. the two types are identical. There is no way to distinguish between these two types. You can use one whereever you can use the other one.

So

```
GenderType gender;
std::string temp;
temp = gender;
```

is the same as

```
std::string gender, temp;
temp = gender;
```

With type aliases, you can't add any type safety.